# Unexpected value 'FormBuilder' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

How to add formbulder in app.module

Unexpected value FormBuilder imported by the module AppModule. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ClientComponent } from './client/client.component';
    import { ClientTaskComponent } from './clienttask/clienttask.component';
    import { ClientService } from './client/sherad/client.service';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent, ClientComponent, ClientTaskComponent, ClientService
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        FormBuilder,
        FormGroup,
        FormControl
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: `FormBuilder` doesn't need to be imported in a module. You should import `ReactiveFormsModule` in the module and inject `FormBuilder` in the component.

Answer (score 4):

`imports` array only accepts Angular Modules.

Instead of

```
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

Just import:

```
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

`ReactiveFormsModule` is the module that `FormBuilder`, `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, `Validators` etc are exposed from. So to use them, you'll have to import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in your Angular Module.

And add just that the `imports` array.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, ClientComponent, ClientTaskComponent, ClientService
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`FormBuilder`, `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, `Validators` etc, should only be imported in the Components/Services and used there. They're not really required in Angular Module Files.

Answer (score 4):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http"; import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'; ........................///Remove this

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";..........//Add this

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ClientComponent } from './client/client.component';
import { ClientTaskComponent } from './clienttask/clienttask.component';
import { ClientService } from './client/sherad/client.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, ClientComponent, ClientTaskComponent, ClientService
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    FormBuilder,.........///Remove this
    FormGroup,...........///Remove this
    FormControl..........///Remove this
    ReactiveFormsModule ..........//Add this
], 
providers: [], 
bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
}) 

export class AppModule { }
```

And import this in your .ts

```
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

Always remember in

```
@NgModule
(
```

**declaration** contains only **components**

**imports** contains only **modules**

**providers** contains only **services**

Answer (score 2):

You cant add FormBuilder to your module you can only add these to your module

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Real and Simple solution that worked in my Code. Just comment these two imports in that particular Module i.e. in my Code HomeModule.ts
Comment these
//FormsModule,
//FormControl